# Is there a way to read a text file in 32 bits assembly in windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, io, masm

How do I write a code which copies a text file using assembly and in windows?
My compiler is masm.

Comment: What do you mean by "copies the file"?

Comment: Masm comes with a lot of example programs. Isn't at least one of them dealing with this?

Comment: So, you want to _read_ that file, or simply create a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, there is a way and yes we can help you. However, you first have to show some effort. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: I know how to write this code in linux my problem is that we can't use interrupts in protected mode assembly code in windows I don't know what syscall to use in windows!

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure whether you want to *read* from the file to memory and do something with that, or simply create a *copy*. In the first case, use [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), otherwise go with [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'll need to link with `kernel32.dll` to be able to use these functions.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, interacting with the OS involves calling API functions rather than making interrupt calls as in Linux.

If you just want to copy the file, call [CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you want to read the file, do some processing, and then write, you'll need `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, and `WriteFile`. (You can find documentation for those functions from the `CopyFile` link above.)

I don't have a link to a good tutorial on calling Windows API functions from assembly language. Searching reveals some information, but nothing that I'd call a good tutorial. You'll have to look for examples and try things.